# Namecheap Problem - Account holder passed away

Tags: dns, namecheap

I have a client who has their DNS registered through Namecheap. The registrant (previous webdeveloper) passed away in August and now my client has no way to access or login to Namecheap to manage his domain name. Needless to say, Namecheap is not being very helpful. My client's name is clearly the registrant of the domain, but the email address of the registrant is the dead guy and we have no way to access his email to gain namecheap access.

I'm kind of stuck now - don't know what kind of process to follow to get control of the client's domain. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "The registrant (previous webdeveloper) passed away" - strictly speaking it would seem to be the "account holder" that passed away, not really the "registrant" - the client's name is recorded as the "registrant", which still makes them the legal registrant. Not being able to access the account to administer the domain is the problem.

Comment: True - although the deceased developer purchased the domains and managed them thru namecheap, he used the client's information as the main registrant, with the exception of email address. And also true, the domains are under the deceased's account. I have to believe there is some kind of process all domain registrars have to follow under these kinds of circumstances, but I can't determine what that process is.

Comment: I wrote an answer here that may help some: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61346/getting-access-to-website-files-without-access-to-the-hosting-account/61347#61347 The idea is to be able to prove that your developer was working on behalf of the company and to quickly gather as much information as possible toward that goal. Registrars/hosts deal with this stuff every day. However, the tech support person is instructed to deflect requests that could be a form of social engineering a take-over. You may have to ask for a supervisor or the legal department. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Hi there are a dispute policy at https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/policy-2012-02-25-en I think this policy will help you or give you some answers. In the future you should advice your client to keep his email in the Admin info and put the email for any one that run the site in Tech. Info like that he can retrive his info. I hope this help.